# mysql: remove duplicates that also contains a break space

Tags: mysql

by mistake i did insert in my mysql some rows that contains duplicates, but these duplicates where not recognized as is because they contain a brak space

```
    eg.
      | id | name    |
       --------------
      |  1 | Apple   |
      |  2 | Apple{b}| //the {b} is just to show the cell actually contains a break space
```

so when i try to remove the duplicates they are not recognized as duplicates...
and when i try to remove just the breaks i get an error because `name` is a `UNIQUE` cell

what's the best practice to fix this issue?

Comment: You can always get rid of those with `REPLACE()`. Since typing a non-breaking space is hard, use [`UNHEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) to spell it out as printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to find or delete records containing space in the end:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE name REGEXP '\s+$';
```

Comment: good. but that also kill ANY name with a space even 'Banana  ', but in my case i just need to kill duplicates

Comment: if the difference is just in that space in the end, then join the table to itself and compare name column using space: `DELETE t1 FROM your_table t1 JOIN your_table t2 ON CONCAT(t2.name,' ')=t1.name;`